# preventing page from refreshing on form submission javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to display a message inside a DIV (which is hidden by default) when I press the Calculate button.
At the moment, when i click Calculate the box briefly appears with the text inside but because the page refreshes it disappears and goes back to the original content.

How can I prevent this from happening? I have looked through other similiar posts, but none of the answers seem to solve my problem.

```
var calc = document.getElementById('form');

calc.addEventListener('submit', calculateAndPrintRisk);
var total;
var riskTotal;
var age;
var bmi;
var diet;
var diabetes;




function calculateRisk() {

  age = document.querySelector('input[name="age"]:checked').value;
  bmi = document.querySelector('input[name="bmi"]:checked').value;
  diabetes = document.querySelector('input[name="diabetes"]:checked').value;
  diet = document.querySelector('input[name="diet"]:checked').value;
  age = parseInt(age);
  bmi = parseInt(bmi);
  diabetes = parseInt(diabetes);
  diet = parseInt(diet);
  total = age + bmi + diabetes + diet;
  return total;

};


function calculateAndPrintRisk() {
  var riskTotal = calculateRisk();

  var panel = document.getElementById("messagePanel");


    if (total <= 15) {

        var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
        var message = document.createTextNode("hello world");
        paragraph.appendChild(message);
        panel.appendChild(paragraph);




    } else if (total <= 25) {

          alert("medium");

   } else {

         alert("high");
     }

  }
```

CSS:

```
#messagePanel{
    width:600px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid black;
    visibility:hidden;
```

HMTL:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>JavaScript FMA</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

    </head>

    <body>

<div id="wrapper">

  <h1>The Diabetes Risk Assesment Tool</h1>
  <div id="Options">
    <form id="form">

      <fieldset>

      <p> How old are you? </p>

      1-25 <input type="radio" name="age" value="0" checked>
       26-40 <input type="radio" name="age" value="5"> 
       41-60 <input type="radio" name="age" value="8">
        60+ <input type="radio" name="age" value="10">
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
      <p> What is your BMI? </p>

      0-25 <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="0" checked>
       26-30 <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="0"> 
       31-35 <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="9"> 
       35+ <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="10">
       </fieldset>

       <fieldset>

      <p> Does anybody in your family have diabetes? </p>

      No <input type="radio" name="diabetes" value="0" checked> 
      Grandparent <input type="radio" name="diabetes" value="7">
       Sibling <input type="radio" name="diabetes" value="15"> 
       Parent <input type="radio" name="diabetes" value="15">
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>


      <p> How would you describe your diet? </p>

      Low sugar <input type="radio" name="diet" value="0" checked>
       Normal sugar <input type="radio" name="diet" value="0"> 
       Quite high sugar <input type="radio" name="diet" value="7">
        High sugar <input type="radio" name="diet" value="10">

        </fieldset>

      <input type="submit" id="calculate" name="button_calculate" value="Calculate">
    </form>

            <div id="messagePanel">
            </div>

  </div>
</div>
<script src="diabetestool.js"> </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You don't want the button to submit, and yet you've used `input type="submit"`. I wonder if maybe there's some *other* `type` you could use that wouldn't submit... If only there were [some way to know](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-type), or some kind of [meta reference site](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/HTML/Element/input.html) one could use...

Comment: The thing is, this is for a university work. So in fact, submiting or not, it is not going to send it to a server or anything like that. The point of the button or input, is just to display a div under it whenever it is pressed displaying a message inside of it depending on the value of "risk".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the type from `submit` to `button`, it will not submit the form.  Then you can change your event handler to handle the button click.

```js
document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", calculateAndPrintRisk);

var total;
var riskTotal;
var age;
var bmi;
var diet;
var diabetes;




function calculateRisk() {

  age = document.querySelector('input[name="age"]:checked').value;
  bmi = document.querySelector('input[name="bmi"]:checked').value;
  diabetes = document.querySelector('input[name="diabetes"]:checked').value;
  diet = document.querySelector('input[name="diet"]:checked').value;
  age = parseInt(age);
  bmi = parseInt(bmi);
  diabetes = parseInt(diabetes);
  diet = parseInt(diet);
  total = age + bmi + diabetes + diet;
  return total;

};


function calculateAndPrintRisk() {
  var riskTotal = calculateRisk();

  var panel = document.getElementById("messagePanel");


    if (total <= 15) {

        var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
        var message = document.createTextNode("hello world");
        paragraph.appendChild(message);
        panel.appendChild(paragraph);

    } else if (total <= 25) {

          alert("medium");

   } else {

         alert("high");
     }
  
  return false;

  }
```

```css
#messagePanel{
    width:600px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid black;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
    <html lang="en>
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>JavaScript FMA</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

    </head>

    <body>

<div id="wrapper">

  <h1>The Diabetes Risk Assesment Tool</h1>
  <div id="Options">
    <form id="form">

      <fieldset>

      <p> How old are you? </p>

      1-25 <input type="radio" name="age" value="0" checked>
       26-40 <input type="radio" name="age" value="5"> 
       41-60 <input type="radio" name="age" value="8">
        60+ <input type="radio" name="age" value="10">
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
      <p> What is your BMI? </p>

      0-25 <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="0" checked>
       26-30 <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="0"> 
       31-35 <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="9"> 
       35+ <input type="radio" name="bmi" value="10">
       </fieldset>

       <fieldset>

      <p> Does anybody in your family have diabetes? </p>

      No <input type="radio" name="diabetes" value="0" checked> 
      Grandparent <input type="radio" name="diabetes" value="7">
       Sibling <input type="radio" name="diabetes" value="15"> 
       Parent <input type="radio" name="diabetes" value="15">
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>


      <p> How would you describe your diet? </p>

      Low sugar <input type="radio" name="diet" value="0" checked>
       Normal sugar <input type="radio" name="diet" value="0"> 
       Quite high sugar <input type="radio" name="diet" value="7">
        High sugar <input type="radio" name="diet" value="10">

        </fieldset>

      <input type="button" id="calculate" name="button_calculate" value="Calculate">
    </form>

            <div id="messagePanel">
            </div>

  </div>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you! this solved the problem I had. apreciate your help

Answer (score -1):

Replace the `<input>` element with a `<button>`.

The Input will submit the form and post back to the server. Use the button element to avoid this.

Comment: So will a `button`. The default `type` of `button` is `submit`.